# Lego Mindstorms EV3 software cannot find brick via WiFi

Tags: networking, xubuntu, wine, 16.04, winetricks

My Lego Mindstorms EV3 software cannot find the EV3 brick via WiFi.  The strange thing is, it works in a fresh install of (X)Ubuntu in Virtualbox *on this computer*, same version.  Things I have tried:

- Recreating the Wineprefix
- Reinstalling Wine
- Using both a wired and wireless connection to the router.

Comment: I don't know what "brick" is, but does ping to it works?

Comment: Yes, it does.  PING 192.168.0.6 (192.168.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=229 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=53.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.6: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=273 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.6: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=91.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.6: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=421 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.6: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=245 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.6: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=62.8 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.6 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 53.67

Comment: Okay, try some things: first execute `sudo service ufw stop` and see if it fixes the problem. If it isn't, tell: do you use in the Lego Mindstorm the exact IP address or some kind of discovery? Also, run the Mindstorm, try again the connection from it, next switch to a terminal *(you may use the one in Alt+Ctrl+F1)*, find the pid of the app, like `ps -A | grep indstorm`, and check what ports it uses with `sudo netstat --all --program | grep InsertPIDHere`. Then run `sudo tcpdump -i any src port InsertPort and dst port InsertPort`, and tell if you see or not both outgoing and incoming packets.

Comment: Ah, I forgot: after you ran the *tcpdump*, switch back with Ctrl+Alt+F7 *(i.e. if you did use the Ctrl+Alt+F1 terminal)*, try to connect again, and then look at the output of the tcpdump.

Comment: `sudo service ufw stop` works!  Any way to keep the firewall on though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a firewall that blocks connections from the brick. The easiest way to fix the problem is to disable firewall by `sudo service ufw stop`, but it's a bad idea in general. Instead, you could setup rules to allow.

I guess, Lego Mindstorm sends a broadcast request, and waits for incoming connections from anyone *(from the brick in our case)*. That means, you need to allow incoming connections either:

- from an interface
- using a subnet
- from a specific IP
- to a specific port
- using a specific protocol *(i.e. http, https, ssh)*
- any combination of above.

So, one rule you could use is `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.6`, since it's the address of your brick. But I don't know how the address is assigned to the brick, whether it is dynamic, and would you want to use it with another one *(with different IP)*, so probably better way would be to find the port in use, and setup a rule for that. First, temporary disable firewall *(`sudo service ufw stop`)*, execute in terminal `sudo tcpdump -nni any src 192.168.0.6 and dst 192.168.0.6`, and connect the app to the brick. You would see an info about packets going between your host and brick, the port is written right after IP of your PC, like *…192.168.0.6.52382 > 192.168.0.1.**80**…* Then you can use:

```
sudo ufw allow PortNumberYouGot # e.g. sudo ufw allow 21
```

or better yet is to allow only a specific subnet:

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/16 to any port PortNumberYouGot
```

Comment: sudo netstat --all --program | grep 17866
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     220927   17866/C:\Program Fi 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     219015   17866/C:\Program Fi 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     220790   17866/C:\Program Fi 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     219017   17866/C:\Program Fi 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     221871   17866/C:\Program Fi

Comment: It seems to use many ports, and may even pick them randomly.

Comment: @user4901968 hm… Well, the lines starting with *unix* are not the droids we're looking for; are there any lines that starts  with *tcp* or *udp*?

Comment: No, just what was pasted.

Comment: It might be something weird with the way Wine works...

Comment: @user4901968 are you sure the app is connected to the brick at the moment you did netstat? And either way, here's another idea: enable ufw back with `sudo service ufw start`, do `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, and try to connect with Lego Mindstorms again. You should see a line[s] appeared, saying something about `UFW BLOCK`. It is messages about blocked connections, the port, I think, is written after the word `DPT`.

Comment: No lines appear.  Also, after enabling UFW, I need to restart the program to make it stop working again.

Comment: @user4901968 right, it worked because when you started, connection already existed, i.e. nothing to deny for UFW. Okay, try then take the same look at the `/var/log/ufw.log`. Perhaps in 16.04 UFW doesn't output into syslog anymore — that makes sense because in some circumstances it really flooded it up with those messages. It the file not there, two things to check: what file mentioned in the `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf`, and does `sudo ufw status verbose` reports "Logging: on (low)"?

Comment: $ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
$ tail -f /var/log/ufw.log
tail: cannot open '/var/log/ufw.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining

Comment: $ cat /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf
# Log kernel generated UFW log messages to file
:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log

# Uncomment the following to stop logging anything that matches the last rule.
# Doing this will stop logging kernel generated UFW log messages to the file
# normally containing kern.* messages (eg, /var/log/kern.log)
#& stop

Comment: @user4901968 That's all so weird… I can only guess ufw is broken somehow. I'd also try to play a bit with logging level of *ufw* and *iptables*, but we're just trying to get info to set a rule rather than debugging *ufw*, so let's just go another way — stop firewall, execute `sudo tcpdump -nni any src 192.168.0.6 and dst 192.168.0.6`, and connect with the brick again. You would see an info about packets going between your host and brick, the port is written right after IP of your PC, like _…192.168.0.6.80 > 192.168.0.1.**52382**…_

Comment: I don't currently have the brick available to test, unfortunately.  Will try next chance.

Comment: FYI that `iptables-save` won't help here - it spits the iptables data to stdout and that won't help in  this case as it doesn't store anywhere

Comment: @ThomasW. Ah, interesting. I found it just for the safe case on some Ubuntu forum. I'll remove the line though, it is probably unneeded anyway.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Context is key - ufw will restore its rule sets and save them - advanced sysadmin and security is `iptables` directly which you use the command `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` with the `iptables-persistent` package to save/restore rule sets.